# Service, activity and notifications

Tags: android

I have program that starts Service.

Service periodically checks server for updates. If there are new updates on server service creates notification. It creates notificatins even if my application is foreground. But I want it to create notification only if my application is background or stopped.

Can you advice me best way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [sendOrderedBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29).  Your service can send that and then have a handler waiting for the response.  Your activity can set a true response if it is open and handles the request.  Then when the handler in the service gets the response it can create the notification if the broadcast was not handled, otherwise it can just ignore it.

In your UI activity set up a BroadcastReceiver like so:

```
//register BroadcastReceiver.  This will probably go in onCreate()
registerReceiver(messageBroadcastListener,
            new IntentFilter("my.intent.INTENT_NAME"));

//Defined elsewhere in your code, I always do these outside of onCreate()
//to keep it clean
BroadcastReceiver messageBroadcastListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if(data != null) {
            //display info or whatever and then:
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }

};
```

In your service use sendOrderedBroadcast() and have a receiver for the result like so:

```
BroadcastReceiver sendMessageResultReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        if(getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //display notification here
          }
     }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml set up the intent filter for your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.intent.INTENT_NAME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm already implementing it. Can you point me, how to register broadcastreciever in androidmanifest.xml?

Comment: nm.  Ignore this.  I'm being stupid.  will answer properly in a second.

Comment: Ok, all sorted out now.  I've added the line to register the BroadcastReceiver in your activity and the intent-filter that goes in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I just realized that in my example above I goofed up the note about the BroadcastReceiver saying to put it in onCreate but it's in the bit about the service.  I am correcting this in case someone comes across this later so that the example will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

i think a flag variable will do the job.
Have a variable in and change them only pendingintent which is execute on clicking the notifications.
Disable the notification when the value is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You're applications' onPause() and onResume() are called when the activity get's covered by another app or comes back to front respectably. You can then just set a public var or call a function on your service.